# How can I ignore the ' character into a SQL Server where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have the following problem with a query on **SQL Server**

I have this simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [PROT_UTENTI]
WHERE 
    Nome = 'Paolo D''Aannuntis'
```

that finds a user by a **Nome** field (representing the name and the surname, I know, it is horrible but I can't change the DB because it is an old legacy application in production).

As you can see the surname (**D'Annuntis**) contains the **'** character (I escaped it by doubling the '').

The problem is that I am performing this query using the **Nome** value extracting it from another databse (it is involved into a migration process) where the same **Nome** field is saved without the **'** character into the surname.

So I am performing this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [PROT_UTENTI]
WHERE 
    Nome = 'Paolo DAannuntis'
```

instead

```
SELECT *
FROM [PROT_UTENTI]
WHERE 
    Nome = 'Paolo D''Aannuntis'
```

finding 0 result.

My question is: there is a way to ignore the **'** so the where clause **Nome = 'Paolo DAannuntis'** can find the same result **Nome = 'Paolo D''Aannuntis'**?

Comment: Why Nome is saved in a different way in migration process, this is modifying data a. I would suggest there is a need to fix the insert/migration process to bring source and destination data aligned.

Comment: Use `REPLACE`? But then any indexes you have will be useless to you.

Comment: @Ven ehhh in an idea world you are right. Because the username was saved differently in the 2 databases and I have to use the value saved in the first one (that  does not contains the ' character) to query the second one that contains name that allow ' character.

Comment: It can work with `replace` however, are u searching values dynamically?

Comment: If you use parametrized queries then you won't have any problem with ' characters. Besides, it's a good practice to always use parameters so you'll never be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: what about a simple `in`? `where nome IN('Paolo DAannuntis', 'Paolo D''Aannuntis')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can replace any ' by nothing in your search query

```
SELECT *
FROM   [PROT_UTENTI]
WHERE  replace(Nome, '''', '') = 'Paolo DAannuntis'
```

you can also do the replace on both sides

```
WHERE  replace(Nome, '''', '') = replace('Paolo D''Aannuntis', '''', '')
```

You wrote that the value is extraced from another database in a migration,
so I guess you will have a variable.

```
declare @nome varchar(100) = 'Paolo D''Aannuntis' -- filled by your process

SELECT *
FROM   [PROT_UTENTI]
WHERE  replace(Nome, '''', '') = replace(@nome, '''', '')
```

this will find your row, regardless if there are quotes or not in the variable or in `[PROT_UTENTU].nome`

this will have affect on the performance of the query, so I hope there are not millions of rows in your table

Comment: His question is other way round he would like name to be searched with `'Paolo D''Aannuntis'`

Comment: @Ven I have edited my answer with an option to search both ways around

Comment: True,The first option will work, however OP has to be clear that the rule applied to every row, not just one hard coded value

Comment: @Ven well I guess the value `Paolo DAannuntis` was just an example, and his actual query will use a variable, or an input from another table